# EF 6, LINQ how to create where inside include with conditional parameter

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6

I have 4 tables

```
tblTraining
-----------
ID
Name

tblQuestion
----------
ID
Name
Active (true / false)
(FK) TrainingID

tblAnswer
----------
ID
Name
Active (true / false)
(FK) QuestionID

tblEmployeeTraining
-------------------------
ID
(FK) EmployeeID
(FK) TrainingID
```

Each Training has many Questions, and each Question has many Answers.
I also have tblEmployeeTraining to store every employee that do the related training.

I wanna to get the training object by training ID,
but I have conditional parameter to include the Question or EmployeeTraining.

So here I call my query:

```
GetTraining(dbContext, ID: 1, includeEmployeeTrainings: true, includeQuestions: false);
```

here my GetTraining Function:

```
public static TrainingCourse GetTraining(dbContext, int ID = 0,
        bool includeEmployeeTrainings = false, bool includeQuestions = false)
    {
        try
        {
            IQueryable<tblTraining> training = (
                    from tc in dbContext.tblTraining
                    select tc);

            //where 
            if (ID != 0) training = training.Where(tc => tc.ID == ID);

            //include
            var includeQuestionQuery = includeQuestions ? training.Select(tc => new
            {
                Questions = tc.tblQuestions.Where(qq => qq.IsActive == true),
                Answers = tc.tblQuestions.Select(qq => qq.tblAnswers.Where(qa => qa.IsActive == true)),
            }) : null;

            var includeEmployeeTrainingsQuery = includeEmployeeTrainings ? training.Select(tc => new
            {
                EmployeeTrainings = tc.tblEmployeeTrainings.AsEnumerable()
            }) : null;

            training = training.Select(tc => new
            {
                tc,
                includeQuestionQuery,
                includeEmployeeTrainingsQuery,
            }).AsEnumerable().Select(tc => tc.tc).AsQueryable();

            return training.FirstOrDefault();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

the above code will work perfectly if I call like this

```
GetTraining(dbContext, 1, includeEmployeeTrainings: true, includeQuestions: true);
```

but get an error if I call like this

```
GetTraining(dbContext, 1, includeEmployeeTrainings: false, includeQuestions: true);
```

> Unable to create a null constant value of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[[<>f__AnonymousType2`1[[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[.....]]'. Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context

I know the error is because in GetTraining Function, the includeEmployeeTrainingsQuery is null. But how do I do solve this problem ?

Comment: Why don't you add an `Include` statement conditionally?

Comment: hi Arnold, what do you mean? could you give example? But if you mean like this "if (includeQuestions) training = training.Include(tc => tc.tblQuestions);". it can't be like this since I need "WHERE" statement inside the include.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that the compiler cannot work out the type of null in your anonymous type variable `training`.

One solution would be to create a strongly typed result using ViewModels. Those can be null using something like `(Viewmodelclass)null`. Or you can simply avoid assigning null using classic if statements, instead of ternary operators:

```
public class QuestionsQueryVm {
    public foo bar {get; set; }
}
public class EmplyeeTrainingVm {
    public foo bar {get; set; }
}


public class TrainingVm {
    public QuestionsVm  Questions { get; set;}
    public EmployeeTrainingsVm EmployeeTraining { get; set; }
    public Training Training
}
```

So now you can start from the top:

```
var training = dbContext.tblTraining.Where(tc => tc.ID == ID)
var trainingVm = new TrainingVm {
    Training = training.FirstOrDefault(), // should be only one
}; 

if(includeQuestions) 
{
   var questions = training.Select(tc => new QuestionsQueryVm
   {
        Questions = tc.tblQuestions.Where(qq => qq.IsActive == true),
        Answers = tc.tblQuestions.Select(qq => qq.tblAnswers.Where(qa => qa.IsActive == true)),
   });
   trainingVm.Questions = questions;
}

if(includeEmployeeTrainings) 
{
    employeeTraining = training.Select(tc => newEmplyoeeTraingVm
    {
         EmployeeTrainings = tc.tblEmployeeTrainings.AsEnumerable()
    });
    trainingVm.EmployeeTraining = employeeTraining;
}
```

Comment: Hi Marco, I assume from your code, you tried to return TrainingVm Object, instead Training Object. But I still want it return Training object, which will has the list of Questions, and inside Questions, there are list of Answers. I don't think I want to create extra view model, just wonder if there is simple and clean solution.

Comment: The keypoint is the first paragraph of my answer. You cannot pass null into annymous objects. The compiler cannot handle this. Strongly typed - no problem. Create the viewmodels and be happy. The code below is just for emphasis.
If you don't want ViewModels, you will have to refactor your code to avoid nulls.